# PHP not loading specific extension if relative path is specified

Tags: php, php7, extension

I have a specific extension that won't load if I specific a relative path in the `extension_dir` parameter. If I specify an absolute path it gets loaded. I can't use absolute path because I often need to move the webserver location and would be annoying to reconfigure all paths each time.

The only difference i notice is that this extension is a `.win` file and not a `.dll`.

PHP version is `PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 16:17:34) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )`

***UPDATE FOR MarkusMüller***

Yes, other extensions are loaded correctly (curl, fileinfo, gd2, mbstring, openssl, php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64) without any problem. The specific extension is `ixed.7.4ts.win` from [SourceGuardian](https://www.sourceguardian.com/) and it's needed to deobfuscate some core files. In the `error.log` i have this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.7.4ts.win' (tried: ext\\ixed.7.4ts.win (The specified module could not be found.), ext\\php_ixed.7.4ts.win.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: So all other extensions load just fine with relative paths? What extension is it? Any error message to share?

Comment: @MarkusMüller I've updated the question with the details you asked

Comment: OK, sometimes the error message is misleading. I think I had that same error once. The "not found" message is also displayed if one of the prerequisites was not found. Does this extension need a special version of the Visual C++ runtime libraries or anything similar?

Comment: @MarkusMüller I didn't find the exact problem but made a new fresh install, downloaded back the extension and now the problem is gone. php.ini is the same by the way so I think there was some other spoiled file that caused this weird behaviour. Thanks anyway!